# Error in the creation of a chat GPT app (API connection successfull but no response)

Tags: android, debugging, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I created a chatGPT Android App. If I ask questions in the app I get the error message invalid response format (Field content not available) however if I spam questions I get the message Question limit reached, buy premium or wait a minute. So the API connection works already fine.

Here is the part of the JSON response object:

```
val responseObject = JSONObject(responseText)
val choicesArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("choices")

if (choicesArray.length() > 0) {
    val completionObject = choicesArray.optJSONObject(0)

    if (completionObject != null && completionObject.has("content")) {
        val completionText = completionObject.getString("content")
        responseTextView.text = completionText
    } else {
        val errorMessage = "Ungültiges Antwortformat: Feld 'content' nicht vorhanden"
        Log.e("Response", errorMessage)
        responseTextView.text = errorMessage
    }
}
```

Also, I attached 2 pictures of the App.

[image]
[image]

Maybe you have an idea what problem there is.

Thank you very much for your help!

I tried to debug this a long time. I read the Open AI Docs and also used Chat GPT for debugging.
The only hint for the current error is the message invalid response format (Field content not available).

Maybe you have an idea.
Thank you very much for your answers!